# Eclipse : How to restore default settings in perspectives?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have lost the "debug" panel/toolbar (with the yellow curly arrow step tools) in my Eclipse debug perspective and cannot get it back.

Clicking the Window | Show View | Debug (beetle) seems to do nothing.

How can I get it back, or restore the default settings (without altering anything else)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the Show view/Debug seems to do nothing, then the view is already visible, that is the main reason it seems to do nothing.

Maybe your view is not visible because you have  moved the view into a hover window (by selecting Detach view from the popup menu of the View header), or turned it into a quick view (in this case the view is shown somewhere on the statusbar in an icon - by default in the lower left corner of the window). If that is the case, then try to move back the Debug view.

Have you tried Reset perspective from the Window menu (of course, when the Debug perspective is active)? This restores the default layout of the Debug perspective, every other setting remains.

My other idea is that you are using the newest Eclipse 3.8/4.2, where a new feature is available to put these icons to the main toolbar: see [following post for details](http://eclipse-debug.blogspot.hu/2011/10/debug-top-level-toolbar.html).

Comment: Thanks +1 and #accepted. I had missed the Reset. I think the window got detached onto a second monitor and I couldn't get it back.

Answer (score 23):

If your Eclipse got messed-up due to any reason. just try

<kbd>Window</kbd> -> <kbd>Reset Perspective</kbd>

and it will reset the layout to the below pic.

[image]

Comment: eclipse juno perspective reset is broken - it somehow does not reset the widget listing annotation actions (c/c++ perspective)

Answer (score 1):

If you want restore then you should delete in

```
cd %USERPROFILE%\eclipse-workspace\
```

the folder

> .metadata