# Modifying keyboard shortcuts in Eclipse doesn't work

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

I have Eclipse running on my Mac. I kinda went and did something stupid and changed the shortcut settings for the Logcat view to show up and set it to (Shift+L). Then I went and removed the shortcut, but it doesn't seem to be changing. I even tried the "restore defaults" option and it does not work. Now I'm not able to type an upper-case L. Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: Did you make the changes for the shortcut in the Eclipse or the MAC system preferences? Did you try rebooting the MAC just to see if the deleted short cut keys took effect?

Comment: Hmm. I haven't tried rebooting. But I will try now and see.

Comment: If that does not work, see if the answer mentioned in this works for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074213/eclipse-how-to-restore-default-settings-in-perspectives

Comment: That solution did not work. :(